new Oracle Linux kernel and graphics card drivers
After an update to last Oracle linux kernel, my second screen doesn't work anymore.
My suspect are related to incompatible drivers and kernel or something similar; the second video output works fine if I use windows or with OL with previous kernel (so, it's a software issue).
Running lspci the result on the 2 kernel versions are:
OLD kernel (5.15.0-210.163.7.el9uek.x86_64):
[XXX.YYY@N2852 ~]$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] [8086:9a60] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8870]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 151, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at 6052000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [8086:9a03] (rev 05)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [T1200 Laptop GPU] [10de:1fbc] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8870]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 150, IOMMU group 17
    Memory at 6d000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 6040000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 6050000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 6e080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
[XXX.YYY@N2852 ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 05)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 05)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 05)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 05)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 05)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCIe Root Port #17 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCIe Root Port #3 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation WM590 LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [T1200 Laptop GPU] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
56:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
57:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5261 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
[XXX.YYY@N2852 ~]$ 

NEW kernel (5.15.0-301... )
[XXX.YYY@N2852 ~]$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] [8086:9a60] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8870]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 150, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at 6052000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant [8086:9a03] (rev 05)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [T1200 Laptop GPU] [10de:1fbc] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

56:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808] (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 970 EVO/PRO [144d:a801]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at 6eb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
[XXX.YYY@N2852 ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 05)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 05)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 05)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 05)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 05)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H Management Engine Interface (rev 11)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCIe Root Port #17 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H PCIe Root Port #3 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation WM590 LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H SPI Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [T1200 Laptop GPU] (rev ff)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev ff)
56:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
57:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5261 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

The controllers used for a couple of devices are different, so, probably the cause is this.
How can I fix it?
